# Internal Server Error on homepage in vue storefront

Tags: internal-server-error, vue-storefront

Got internal server error on the homepage during initial load. error log within the vue-storefront.log reports as follows:

```
[search] Can not connect the vue-storefront-api / ElasticSearch instance! Error: {"code":500,"result":{"diagnosticText":"src/processor/default.ts(25,48): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'string | Query | (string | Query)[] | ((searchString: string, position?: number) => number) | ((searchElement: string | Query, fromIndex?: number) => number)' has no compatible call signatures.\n","diagnosticCodes":[2349]}}
    at SearchAdapter.exports.modules../core/lib/search/adapter/api/searchAdapter.ts.SearchAdapter.handleResult (vsf-search-adapter-0.server-bundle.js:519:23)
```

a similar bug seems to have been reported earlier: https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront/issues/3259
Has someone else encountered anything similar and has a solution for this?

---

While installing vue storefront, I got this error log within in the vue-storefront.log (i chose not to use the demo.vuestorefront.io as the backend) :

```
ERROR in ./src/themes/default/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/compat-data/corejs3-shipped-proposals'
```

- OS: Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6
- Node: v 14.1.0
- Yarn: v 1.22.4

I deleted the yarn.lock file as well as the node_modules directory, repeated the process and the installation succeeded. I just wanted to mention this along just in case.